# How does Index Merge intersection provide optimization in mysql/rdbms?

Tags: mysql, indexing, rdbms

I am trying to understand indexing in RDBMS, and I am having hard time understanding Index Merge Intersection optimization while executing SQL query. Let's take this query as example

```
SELECT * FROM innodb_table
  WHERE primary_key < 10 AND key_col1 = 20;
```

Suppose we have two indices, one for each key column. How does using index merge benefit us here?

For e.g. we can use index of primary_key column to do range scan, and then do a linear scan of intermediate results to get the expected output.

How can Index Merge give us better performance?

Comment: with one of the two keys being a primary key, you shouldn't be seeing an index merge, at least on any recent version

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think it gives better performance?  Sometimes it may; it would depend a lot on the cardinality of the indexes and particular values/ranges being searched.

In practice, it often means you should pick which index will perform better and add an index hint.

Comment: I can't think of a scenario where index merge will be preferable over linear scanning? Can you give me an example?

Comment: several low cardinality keys being index merged where a very low number of rows will be selected and each table row is quite large?

Answer (score 0):

For `WHERE primary_key < 10 AND key_col1 = 20`, provide

```
INDEX(key_col1, primary_key)
```

*in that order*.  Discussion:

- Put `=` columns first in the index; one 'range' last.
- Index merge might be usable without the above 'composite' index, but it will not be as efficient.
- It would be specifically "index merge intersect" (as opposed to "... union").
- I have yet to find a case where index merge intersect is faster than a suitable composite index.

How would merge work?

1. Gather a list of PKs satisfying `primary_key < 10`
2. Gather a list of PKs satisfying `key_col1 = 20`
3. "merge" those two lists ("AND").
4. Use the PKs to look up the row(s) (`SELECT *`).

How would the composite key work?

1. Using the index's BTree, locate the first 'row' in the index with `key_col1 = 20`; it will have the smallest `primary_key`.
2. Reach into the table to get `SELECT *` using the PK.
3. Move on to the next row in the index.
4. Repeat steps 2, 3 until hitting `10`.

Without the composite index, *probably* this is what the optimizer will do:

1. Start at the beginning of the table (no index being used)
2. Ignore row if `key_col1 = 20` is false; else deliver row
3. repeat until `primary_key < 10`

`EXPLAIN SELECT ...` will tell you which method it chose.

As for index merge union...

- It is only(?) used with `OR`.
- It is rarely used.
- Sometimes reformulating the query to use `UNION` instead of `OR` is a better option.